# How to open a file in NERDTree and show it in a new tmux window?

Tags: vim, tmux, nerdtree

My setup is Vim + Tmux. And I use NERDTree for simple navigation.

I'm often in a situation where I have two files open side by side, and I want to open a third file for reference in full size and being able to switch between the side by side view of the two first files and the full-size view of the third file.

So now, I would have to:

1. open a new Tmux window
2. open vim
3. find and open the third file

, then I can use tmux to switch between the side by side view and the full-size view.

I wonder if it's possible to open a file in NERDTree and show it in a new tmux window? Or how do you deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the plugin [tmux-open](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-open) but, don't know if it allows to open in new panel/window/session.

Comment: Not exactly solved my issue, but the plugin looks very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the concept of vim tabs.

You can open a file, then split using something like `:vnew` for example.

Then, you can use `:tabnew filename.smt` and that will be opened in a new full-size view (that you can either split again or keep as it is).

Then, with `:tabp` you can go to the previous tab and with `:tabn` to the next.

Obviously it's easier if you map some shortcuts, but you get the idea.

Comment: There's `gt` and `gT` to switch tabs.